# Azure iOS pipeline get failed after xCode 11.4

Tags: ios, xcode, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

After updating the Xcode version to 11.4 or 11.4.1 or 11.5 getting following error. The pipeline is working fine on 11.3.1 version. Does anyone facing same issue?

```
xcrun: error: missing DEVELOPER_DIR path: /Applications/Xcode_11.5.app/Contents/Developer
```

Even if I set xCode version to default, it is picking xCode 11.3.1 whereas on Azure documentation it said default version is 11.4.1.

https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-image-generation/blob/master/images/macos/macos-10.15-Readme.md

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my test, when I used `macOS-10.15` hosted agent to run, the default version of Xcode was `11.4.1`.

[image]

You can check whether you use `macOS-10.15` image in the pipleine log.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Hugh Lin - MSFT. This helped to solve the issue.